# What is the best practice for sharing code between two TFS GIT projects?

Tags: git, version-control, tfs

We are currently using TFS 2013 with GIT set up with different projects for major groups.  The catch is that I have a couple of libraries where I need to share different branches of a project with other projects.  For example, Project1 and Project2 use a general version and Project3 uses a modified version of the same library.  A quick overview is:

Project1
-- shared code\branch1

Project2
-- shared code\branch1

Project3
-- shared code\branch2

Shared code project
-- shared code\branch1
-- shared code\branch2

I would of course like to be able to merge changes as needed back and forth between branch1 and branch2.

So far, my best idea is to create the shared code project with a local git directory for each branch and then try to do the merges in TFS.  Each project would then access the branch directory that it needed.  This seems rather messy (especially across multiple developer machines).

Any suggestions or comments?  Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm coming across the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of Git for TFS has all the core features of git proper.

So if you assume a structure that is as follows you have projects `P1` and`P2` and you have a library `L` and a descendent of that library `L'`.  If `P1` uses `L` and `P2` uses `L'`.

The `Git` way to handle this is to manage `L'` as a `clone` of `L`. Because you are using a DVCS you can use `L` as an upstream repository for `L'`. This will allow you to pull in all or some of the changes for `L` into `L'` without the differences for `L'` required for `P2` interfering with `P1`

This is basically the github `forking` model [found here](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork). Although these instructions were written with github in mind they are valid for any `.git` repositories.

Additionally this is similar to the way linux kernel development works. The vanilla kernel is maintained by `kernel.org` and the modified kernels for the various distros(RedHat, Arch, etc.) are maintained as forks. The forks are periodically synced with the mainline and the changes are merged to support features of the distro's version of the kernel.

Comment: For what it's worth:  it is *not* based on Git for Windows.  But that's an implementation detail.

Comment: Well, to be fair we haven't talked much about the underlying technology that we use in TFS, on the server side.  (It's not secret, it's just not that exciting).  We also mistakenly wrote that we used Git for Windows ourselves; so it's something that we haven't really clarified much ourselves!